# space before \_ in Equation

Tags: equations, underscore

```
\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
CPU\_time=\sum\limits_{i}^{n_1}{T\_int_{i}}+ \sum\limits_{}^{n_2}{T\_exe_{i}}+\sum\limits_{}^{n_3}{T\_gc_{i}}
\end{aligned}
\label{eq:cputime}
\end{equation}
```

will results in a formula in the picture.

I notice that there is a space before `_`. In the LaTeX code, if I remove `\` before `_`, the formula is not what I expect.

So how to remove the extra space before `_`?

[image]

Comment: See if `\text{CPU}\!\_time` gives what you expected. For this you need to load `amsmath` or `mathtools` package in preamble. To me is more sensible to write `T_{\text{CPU}}` ...

Comment: @Zarko Please don't use/promote `\text` here, it is not meant for this use (especially since it will be italic is the surrounding text (outside math) is italic) .

Comment: @daleif, you are right. And this was not first time that I make this sin :-(. It seems that I'm to old to remember, that I need to `\text` add two more `tt` to achieve right command (as follows from Henry Menke answer :-) ).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Initial Solution

`CPU_time` etc. seem to be variables in a computer program.  It is common in computer science to typeset variables in a typewriter font.  In LaTeX this can be achieved using `\texttt`.  It is more convenient, though, to define an extra macro for typesetting variables, which I call `\var` and define like

```
\newcommand\var{\texttt}
```

If you now want to change the appearance of all variables in the document to, say, sans-serif, it suffices to use `\newcommand\var{\textsf}` instead.

It is tedious to always type `\_` when one wants to have the underscore character in text.  Also `\_` always chooses the underscore character from the roman font family, which might look awkward when used together with a typewriter font.  The [`underscore`](https://ctan.org/pkg/underscore) package lets you type bare `_` in text to typeset an underscore while still acting as the subscript operator in math mode.  It also chooses the underscore from the correct font.

With help of the [`amsmath`](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package you can use all the `\text...` commands in math mode as well, so you don't have to define any branching for your `\var` command.  Remember, that in the arguments of the `\text...` commands spaces are *not* ignored, i.e.

```
\texttt{CPU_time} ≠ \texttt{CPU_time }
```

You use `\sum\limits` which is redundant in display mode and disrupts line spacing in text mode, so better just use `\sum`.

With all the above modifications, the code and the output have a nice and coherent style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{underscore}
\newcommand\var{\texttt}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \var{CPU_time}
  = \sum_i^{n_1} \var{T_int}_i
  + \sum_i^{n_2} \var{T_exe}_i
  + \sum_i^{n_3} \var{T_gc}_i
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Revised Solution

As @egreg mentioned in the comments, this approach might be problematic, because `\text...` is subject to surrounding font changes.  To overcome this it is advantageous to reset to `\normalfont` for the course of `\var`.  LaTeX offers smart macros for the definition of new font commands which we exploit in this improved example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{underscore}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\var}{\normalfont\ttfamily}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
  Theorems put everything in italic \texttt{including typewriter}
  \begin{equation*}
    \var{CPU_time}
    = \sum_i^{n_1} \var{T_int}_i
    + \sum_i^{n_2} \var{T_exe}_i
    + \sum_i^{n_3} \var{T_gc}_i
  \end{equation*}
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Alternative Solution

@egreg also proposed in the comments to use `\mathtt` instead of `\texttt` for the same reason as noted before.  Now we can no longer exploit the `underscore` package, but have to make `_` active for the argument to `\var`.  This needs a lot more code and we lose the underscore from the typewriter font, which is now replaced by `\textunderscore` (through `\_`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\begingroup
\catcode`_=13
\gdef\var{%
  \begingroup
    \catcode`_=13
    \def_{\_}%
    \dovar
}
\gdef\dovar#1{%
    \mathtt{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\endgroup
\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
  Theorems put everything in italic \texttt{including typewriter}
  \begin{equation*}
    \var{CPU_time}
    = \sum_i^{n_1} \var{T_int}_i
    + \sum_i^{n_2} \var{T_exe}_i
    + \sum_i^{n_3} \var{T_gc}_i
  \end{equation*}
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Actual Solution

And to answer the actual question, we can replace here `\mathtt` by `\mathit` and `\_` by `\!\_` to achieve a reduction of the space before the underscore.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begingroup
\catcode`_=13
\gdef\var{%
  \begingroup
    \catcode`_=13
    \def_{\!\_}%
    \dovar
}
\gdef\dovar#1{%
    \mathit{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\endgroup
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \var{CPU_time}
  = \sum_i^{n_1} \var{T_int}_i
  + \sum_i^{n_2} \var{T_exe}_i
  + \sum_i^{n_3} \var{T_gc}_i
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you also show the output with `\mathit` instead of `\mathtt`(that's what I'd use, not `\texttt`)?

Comment: @egreg These variables are derived from some source code (?), so their initial representation is textual.  Thus I would not use math mode to typeset these.

Comment: Try `$\var{CPU_time}$`, with your definition, inside the statement of a theorem and you'll know why `\mathtt` is preferable to `\texttt`.

Comment: @egreg Then I propose `\DeclareTextFontCommand{\var}{\normalfont\ttfamily}`.

Comment: @egreg I hope my revisions address your concerns.